# React JSX style guide

Tags: coding-style, reactjs

What is the standard style for jsx? Specifically when HTML is intertwined with js. Are the parenthesis after return in the correct spot? Anyone know of any good formatters that don't mess everything up?

```
render: function(){
    return (
      <li>
        <input id={this.props.id} type="checkbox" />
        <label htmlFor={this.props.id}>{this.props.tag}</label>
      </li>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

I like to use [Airbnb code style](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/react)
with [Web Storm Editor](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) provide good support for jsx syntax.

*Note:* you can apply Airbnb style automatically inside Web Storm from `Settings->Code Quality`

---

```
render() {
  return (
    <MyComponent className="long body" foo="bar">
      <MyChild />
    </MyComponent>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Found a good style guide here
https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/blob/master/react/README.md